# Java Program Tuning

Tags: java, algorithm, performance

I am interested in hearing others views on how the following piece of code could be tuned for performance. My thoughts are that the run method could be recursively called 20 times rather than a simple iterative loop:

```
class Looper extends Thread {

    @Override
    public void run() {
        for(int i=0; i<10; i++) {
            heavyLogicGoesHere();
        }
    }

    void heavyLogicGoesHere() {
        System.out.println((new java.util.Random().nextInt()));
    }
}

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Looper worker1 = new Looper();
        worker1.run();

        Looper worker2 = new Looper();
        worker2.run();
    }
}
```

Comment: What? Why should recursion be better than iteration? This is generally FAAAAR too broad, the performance improvements depend **heavily** on the task being done, there is no general answer. If there were one you can easily find it by googling.

Comment: There's no point in extending Thread since `run()` is invoked directly (instead of calling `start()`).  So the `worker`s run sequentially, not concurrently.  For the trivial example, running sequentially _might_ actually be faster.

Answer (score 0):

If the `heavyLogicGoesHere` can work independently, why don't you create a thread pool and process it simultaneously.
My suggestion is:

```
class Looper extends Thread {

 @Override
 public void run() {
   heavyLogicGoesHere();
 }

 void heavyLogicGoesHere() {
    System.out.println((new java.util.Random().nextInt()));
 }
}
```

Your main function can be implemented:

```
 ExecutorService executor = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(5);
 for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    Looper worker = new Looper("" + i);
    executor.execute(worker);
 }
 executor.shutdown();
 while (!executor.isTerminated()) {
   //Thread sleep 
 }
 System.out.println("Finished all threads");
```

Answer (score 0):

Since the performance hotspot is in `heavyLogicGoesHere()`, it doesn't make one bit of difference how you do the 10 calls. A `for` loop is the most readable, so there's no reason (certainly not performance) to try to introduce recursion here.

What you should be tuning is `heavyLogicGoesHere()`, assuming of course there is heavy logic inside and not just printing a random int as in the example. After all, if you spend $200 / month on ice cream and $20 / month on toilet paper, you're not going to start "tuning" your toilet paper use.

You're also extending `Thread` (instead of implementing `Runnable`) and calling `run()` instead of `start()`, so the code is wrong in more ways than one. I suggest you forget performance optimization until you actually need it. First you need to concentrate on writing correct code.